# How to add shared drive to google drive

Tags: google-drive

I'm using Google Suite and I have added my Google drive to Ubuntu online accounts.

I can see my Google drive and its content when I open the File Explorer. I have tried and successfully given all permissions from Google to Ubuntu gnome online accounts.

The problem is that I cannot see or add my shared drives, is there a way to do that?

Comment: I am using Insync for this, works quite OK. It's not free.

Comment: If you use "google-drive-ocamlfuse", follow this guide: https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse

Answer (score 6):

Update Q1 2022: this seems to be possible with current versions of Gnome:
[image: Screenshot showing Shared drives]
[image]

---

This is currently (Q3 2019) not possible without additional (non-free or non-oss) software.

There are open issues on Gnome's GitLab issue tracker:

- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-online-accounts/issues/6
- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gvfs/issues/377
- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libgdata/issues/25

as well as on ODrives Github issue tracker:

- https://github.com/liberodark/ODrive/issues/44

At least [insync](https://www.insynchq.com/i/linux) (commercial) claims to give *offline access to Google's Shared Drives for flexible and productive workflows.* There may be support in other commercial offerings.

Comment: Looks like this will come natively with Ubuntu 21.04, according to the second link (gvfs #377). Only one more week to wait .

Comment: @DidierL can you verify that shared drives area available in Ubuntu 21.04? Can this functionality be achieved by upgrading Gnome in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: @Stefan_EOX [this comment](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gvfs/-/issues/377#note_1050191) on the second issue from the list above claims that this feature is available in Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: @Stefan_EOX yes it works now, I see a "Shared with me" folder. I don’t think you can upgrade Gnome without upgrading the rest. If you are ready to go that way, why wouldn’t you switch to a non-LTS Ubuntu version?

Comment: General afraidness, I guess, stops me from updating Ubuntu. ;-) Thanks for your confirmation. Btw, the next LTS is said to be available by 21st of April '22: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/01/ubuntu-22-04-release-features

Comment: If you use "google-drive-ocamlfuse", follow this guide: https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, but reading the answer above in late 2023 I was confused why it was not working for me on the latest Gnome Version on ArchLinux.

**Rebooting my PC fixed it for me**. The additional "shared drives" suddenly appeared.