# Not able to view Google Shared drives in Files

Tags: 20.04

I have ubuntu 20.04... I used Gnome online accounts and added my google drive account.
Once added, I opened files and saw my google drive account as a mounted drive, and can access all files.
But, I also have a shared drive in Google drive, which is not shown in the files.

How to connect to it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 19.04 how to add shared drive to google drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165107/ubuntu-19-04-how-to-add-shared-drive-to-google-drive)